R multiply each element of a vector with another vector
I'm trying to multiply two vectors of unequal length where I want the all the elements of one vector multiplied by all the elements of another vector.
> p
[1] 18.59 18.58 18.54 18.81 18.33

> ret
[1] 1.00 1.01 1.02

Output:
c(18.59, 18.58 18.54 18.81 18.33, 18.78, 18.58, 18.36, 18.44, 18.51, 18.96, 18.77, 18.54, 18.63, 18.70)

I have tried doing p*(1+ret) but I get this error:

Warning message: In p * (1 + ret) :   longer object length is not a
multiple of shorter object length

I don't want to use the for loop but rather vectorize this operation. How do I do this?

c(outer(p, ret))
